# Finding the set of points on a line that have any integer coordinates in 3D space, given a direction and origin.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, multivariable-calculus, 3d

I'm working on a project where I have a 3D grid and an object with a known position and direction. I'm struggling to think of a way to find all of the points on the direction line where any of the three coordinates (x, y, or z) are integer values. My problem is that I need a way to find these points in order by distance from the object's position, so I can't just find them all and then sort them by said distance.

[This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62gwP.png)
hopefully depicts what I'm looking for. I want to find the coordinates of all of the blue points (but in 3D instead of 2D). I think a start would be to find the slope of the line, but I'm not really sure where to go from there.

Any help with this would be seriously appreciated!

Edit: After some thought, I've come up with a way to rephrase this question:

**Given a 3-dimensional vector's origin and orientation, will the vector first pass through an x-integer plane, a y-integer plane, or a z-integer plane? Where is that intersection?**

Comment: Given a point $p = (p_x,p_y,p_z)$ and a direction $v = (v_x,v_y,v_z)$, every point on the line through $p$ with direction $v$ can be written in the form $p + tv$ for some real number $t$.  That is, every point on the line will have coordinates of the form
$$
(x,y,z) = (p_x + tv_x, p_y + tv_y, p_z + tv_z)
$$
for some real number $t$.

Comment: And you can solve for instance $x=p_x+t v_x$ for $t$ If $v_x\not=0$  for any $x$. In particular when $x$ is an (arbitrary)  integer.